# Is it possible to print javascript array in the same php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This page is `mypage.php`.  I need to post the array in this same page.
I had an input field and when i click the button , the value should be saved to an array.Then i need to show all the values in array without page refresh.

```
<input name="name">
<table>
<td>Name</td>
<?php
if(isset($POST['res'])){
$myarr = json_encode($_POST['res']);
foreach($myarr as $a){ ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $a['product'] ?> </td></tr>
<?php } } ?>
</table>

<i onclick="sumpup()" class="glypcon glyphicon-arrow-right" ></i>
<script>
var myarr=[];
    function sumup() {
        var a = document.getElementById('name').value;
        myarr.push({'product': a});
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'mypage.php',
            data: {res: JSON.stringify(myarr)},
            success: function (response) {

            }        })
    }
</script>
```

I need to post the array in the same page.And show the value in a table.
 The important thing is , the page should not be reloaded and when i click the button , i should show the table with array.

Actually am getting the array as params. But i cant print the array. 
Please help me.

Comment: There is no `params` option. Should be `data`. You need to loop over `response` and create the html needed there. Also please use browser console to check for errors

Comment: `url : ''mypage.php,` - Is wrong and the console should be complaining.

Comment: o. sorry for the mistakes. i have edited. I just tried with params. data also not working

Comment: @athira please don't edit the code in your post unless that was a copy & paste error.

Comment: actualy i typed the code here. so some mistakes. like url page name and params

Comment: You don't have an element with name as its id. Don't use `name` for naming any element, variable, ...

Answer (score 0):

$myarr = json_encode($_POST['res']);

This should be $myarr = json_decode ($_POST['res'],true);

You stringified the red already you need to convert it to php array